# What happens to Transaction if TransactionScope.Complete not called at the end of the Using block

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, transactionscope

I am using the SQL Server 2012 and There are multiple SQL Connections to same database inside the `TransactionScope` Using block. But if first Update SQL Operation does not result desired output then I am skipping next call to SQL Operation and also call to `TransactionScope.Complete` not called at the end of the `Using` block.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope#completing-a-transaction-scope

Comment: Thank you @TheGeneral . Can you post as an anwser, so that i can accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will an inner transaction scope roll back if the outer transaction scope doesn't complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497910/will-an-inner-transaction-scope-roll-back-if-the-outer-transaction-scope-doesnt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the information you need is fairly well laid out here [Completing a transaction scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/transactions/implementing-an-implicit-transaction-using-transaction-scope#completing-a-transaction-scope)

> When your application completes all the work it wants to perform in a
>   transaction, you should call the Complete method only once to inform
>   the transaction manager that it is acceptable to commit the
>   transaction. It is very good practice to put the call to Complete as
>   the last statement in the using block.
>
> **Failing to call this method aborts the transaction**, because the
>   transaction manager interprets this as a system failure, or equivalent
>   to an exception thrown within the scope of the transaction. However,
>   calling this method does not guarantee that the transaction wil be
>   committed. It is merely a way of informing the transaction manager of
>   your status. After calling the Complete method, you can no longer
>   access the ambient transaction by using the Current property, and
>   attempting to do so will result in an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Failing to call the transaction complete will cause in the abortion of the transaction, that is the reason why it is a a **very good parcitce** to call `transaction.complete();`

What will happen is that the transaction manager will interpret it as system failure and will throw exceptions (happened to me once, not nice), however and it is a big ***however***,  it does not promise the transaction will be committed so you will have to call commit as well.

*for example:*

```
       using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
            {
                // Opening the connection automatically enlists it in the 
                // TransactionScope as a lightweight transaction.
                connection1.Open();

                // Create the SqlCommand object and execute the first command.
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandText1, connection1);
                returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue);

                // If you get here, this means that command1 succeeded. By nesting
                // the using block for connection2 inside that of connection1, you
                // conserve server and network resources as connection2 is opened
                // only when there is a chance that the transaction can commit.   
                using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectString2))
                {
                    // The transaction is escalated to a full distributed
                    // transaction when connection2 is opened.
                    connection2.Open();

                    // Execute the second command in the second database.
                    returnValue = 0;
                    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandText2, connection2);
                    returnValue = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command2: {0}", returnValue);
                }
            }

            // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
            // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
            scope.Complete();

        }
```

the commit will happen at the end of the using block, that is **if the `TransactionScope` object created the work initially**. Else, the commit will occur **whenever the `commit` line was called**.